# Office.context.mailbox.restUrl doesn't seem to work

Tags: outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-restapi

I have an Outlook web addin that at some point calls the rest API to mark an e-mail with a flag.

This works as expected within my Outlook 2016 Windows client (on an Office 365 account), but on a different system (I believe the setup here is Exchange 2013 SP2 and Outlook 2013 clients) everything appears to work except getting the rest URL.

**Office.context.mailbox.restUrl** simply returns *undefined* which of cause makes the following rest call fail.

Permissions are set correctly to *ReadWriteMailbox* (or it wouldn't work on my own system), but I'm not sure if version of the other setup simply doesn't support this feature?

The manifest contains a section like this:

```
<VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
<Requirements>
  <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
    <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
  </bt:Sets>
</Requirements>
```

But I'm not sure if that changes anything.

Anyone has an idea as to what the problem could be here?

Comment: Should the DefaultMinVersion be set to 1.5 and would that give any limitations to the versions of Exchange server/Outlook client it would work on?

Comment: Hmm if I'm understanding this right, the reason it works on my system is that it is Office 2016 (which supports 1.5) and doesn't work on Office 2013 (which supports only 1.4). To use the rest API version 1.5 is required - Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

I believe there could be two reasons for why this doesn't work, and you appear to have found the first one:

API requirements set 1.5 is needed to access the property Office.context.mailbox.restUrl. This does not depend on the manifest.xml file DefaultMinVersion, but rather the actual Outlook client version you are running. DefaultMinVersion simply blocks your application from running in clients which do not support the specified requirements set. Office 2013 does not support 1.5.

The other possibility may be that your Exchange server does not support REST. The documentation says: "Outlook clients connected to on-premises installations of Exchange 2016 with a custom REST URL configured will return an invalid value for restUrl." (https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.5/Office.context.mailbox?product=outlook).

I searched a bit more into this, wondering if ANY on-premise Exchange setup would support REST, and found that either a hybrid or pure Exchange Online (Office 365) setup is required (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/0503a37d-7869-4c39-a5c3-605e147e2079/support-for-rest-api-in-exchange-2016-onprem-only?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment).

Comment: Official announcement on hybrid requirement for on premises support for REST API: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/exchange/2016/09/26/on-premises-architectural-requirements-for-the-rest-api/

Comment: One thing that I did find out is of cause that API 1.5+ is required, but the very "uncool" thing I also found out is that Outlook 2016 exists in 2 different versions: MSI-installation (has API 1.4) and C2R-installation (has API 1.6) - so only the latter version has the required API version though they are both Outlook 2016... Very uncool.

Comment: Indeed @Aidal, this list of version compatibility is officially documented on this page: https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/tutorial-api-requirement-sets